# how to set transition to mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, mouse

I would like to add transition to my webpage with custom scrolling (I am skipping lines at a faster-than-normal rate). My code is as follow -

```
<html>

<head>

<script>

var MOUSE_WHEEL_GAIN = 1000;

function OnMouseWheel() {

  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollTop - event.wheelDelta/120 * MOUSE_WHEEL_GAIN);

  var e = window.event;
  e.returnValue = false;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  return false;

}

</script>

<head>

<body ONMOUSEWHEEL="OnMouseWheel()">

<script>
for (i=0;i<20;i++) document.write("<p>" + i + " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>");
</script></body></html>
```

I want the code to make the scroll appear as a smooth transition. Is `Javascript` the way or should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

The most compute efficient using way of doing this utilizing DOM-L3:

```
//HTML BLOCK
<canvas onmousemove="TrackMouse(event)"></canvas>

//JS BLOCK
function TrackMouse(e){
        window.scrollBy(e.webkitMovementX, e.webkitMovementY);
}
```